# Merge two equal-length lists into a dictionary, mapping one-to-many

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists with an equal number of elements.  The position of each element corresponds between the lists. One of lists has repeated elements while the other does not.

How can I create a dictionary from the two lists where a key from `Lst1` can be mapped to multiple values in `Lst2`?

```
Lst1 = ['11', '13', '11', '12', '11', '13', '12', '12', '12', '13', '11']
Lst2 = ['1/41', '1/34', '1/37', '1/47', '1/41', '1/33', '1/46', '1/45', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']
```

result:

```
Dict1 = {'11': ['1/41', '1/37', '1/141', 'p6'],
         '12': ['1/47', '1/33', '1/46', 'p4'],
         '13': ['1/34', '1/33', 'p5']}
```

from the two list- wanting to create `Dict1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zip the two lists together and gather repeating values in a list in a new dictionary:

```
Dict1 = {}
for key, val in zip(Lst1, Lst2):
    Dict1.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

Demo:

```
>>> Lst1 = ['11', '13', '11', '12', '11', '13', '12', '12', '12', '13', '11']
>>> Lst2 = ['1/41', '1/34', '1/37', '1/47', '1/41', '1/33', '1/46', '1/45', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']
>>> Dict1 = {}
>>> for key, val in zip(Lst1, Lst2):
...     Dict1.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
... 
>>> Dict1
{'11': ['1/41', '1/37', '1/41', 'p6'], '13': ['1/34', '1/33', 'p5'], '12': ['1/47', '1/46', '1/45', 'p4']}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(Dict1)
{'11': ['1/41', '1/37', '1/41', 'p6'],
 '12': ['1/47', '1/46', '1/45', 'p4'],
 '13': ['1/34', '1/33', 'p5']}
```

Comment: cool.. i was struggling with type error and what not..thank you..as a followup if i can ask a question I would like to pop up one of the odd-man-out in the dict and save it elsewhere...e.g '11': ['1/41', '1/37', '1/41', 'p6'] .-- i want to pop out p6 and save in a variable.

Comment: @user3621625 You'll have to define how you determine it is the odd one out; you can easily loop over the dictionary and apply some code to each lists but you'd need to have a rule to find the odd one first.

Comment: If your dataset is massive (as mine typically are) you'll want to avoid "zip" -- just iterate an index over the length.  I know it's not "pythonic", but it's efficient for very large data structures.

Comment: @Bogatyr `zip` returns an iterator in Python 3. `izip` does the same in Python 2. Doesn't that help when dealing with "massive datasets" ?

Comment: @Bogatyr: in Python 2 you'd use `itertools.izip` in that case.

Comment: @Sylvain and Martijn: sounds good, thanks for the pointers.   I still use Python 2.

Comment: @Martijn thank u.  basically the dictionary 
dict1= {'11': ['1/41', '1/37', '1/41', 'p6'],
 '12': ['1/47', '1/46', '1/45', 'p4'],
 '13': ['1/34', '1/33', 'p5']}   need to split into dict2 and dict3
dict2 ={'11': ['1/41', '1/37', '1/41'],
 '12': ['1/47', '1/46', '1/45'],
 '13': ['1/34', '1/33'']}  and dict3 ={'11': ['p6'],
 '12': ['p4'],
 '13': ['p5']}.  notice dict3 does not list elements with "/"

Comment: @alala then build those two dictionaries immediately; add to one or the other based on the `if '/' in val:` test.